# Mongo - Replace all occurrences of a String

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo database collection, with _id and value as the two keys. What I'm trying to accomplish is to search all the documents in my collection for occurrences of a specific string and replace that with a new string.

```
{
    "_id" : "12345678",
    "value" : "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

Also, extending it further, can I accomplish the same when I have a nested document structure?

```
{
    "_id" : "12345678",
    "someKey" : {
        "value1" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "value2" : "Lorem ipsum"
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.application.find({},{ "ref_no": 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
doc.ref_no = doc.ref_no.trim();
db.application.update(
   { "_id": doc._id },
   { "$set": { "ref_no": doc.ref_no } }
);
})
```